# Archived content documents not found in SOQL

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, contentdocument, archive

This soql is not retrieving any records, any issue in soql ?

```
SELECT Id, Title, FileType, ContentSize FROM ContentDocument ALLROWS WHERE isArchived = true
```

Comment: it seems like from documentation we are suppose to add ALLROWS at the end of the query try adding it at the end like SELECT Id, Title, FileType, ContentSize FROM ContentDocument WHERE isArchived = true  ALLROWS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [ALL ROWS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm), you have to place it at the end of your query, and is 2 keywords. For it to work, update your query to:

```
SELECT Id, Title, FileType, ContentSize FROM ContentDocument WHERE isArchived = true ALL ROWS
```

Please note the query editor does not support an `ALL ROWS` query, so use anonymous apex to validate.